# Creating dirs, copying file, writing content into the files

Tags: php

There are some posts here, but they don't work for me. My need is described in the comments. As a poor beginner, I read many possible online manuals, but can't find the solution.

```html
<?php 
//  BASIC STRUCTURE //
//  ./core/
//  ./core/index.gen
//  ./data/
//  ./data/<dir_name>
//  ./data/<dir_name>/<file_name>
//  ./data/<dir_name>/index.php - for <dir_name> listing
//  ./data/index.php - for ./data/ listing
//  BASIC OPERATION
//  1. create a subdirectory in ./data/
//  2. copy the ./core/index.gen to new created subdirectory
//  3. create new file in new created directory in ./data/
 
$base_dir  = './data';
$dir_name  =  '';
$file_name =  '';
$data_dir = $_GET['data_dir'];
//Check if the directory with the name already exists
if (!is_dir($base_dir.$data_dir)) {
//Create our directory if it does not exist
 mkdir($base_dir.'/'.$data_dir);
 $msg = 'SUCCESS';
 touch($base_dir.'/'.$data_dir.'/'.$_GET['file_name'].'.html');
// copy index.gen from ./core/ to new created dir
     copy($base_dir.'dir_index.php',$base_dir.'/'.$data_dir.'.index.php');
}else{
 $msg = 'ERROR';
}
// read directory content
function getFiles(){
    $items=array();
    if($dir=opendir('.')){
        while($item=readdir($dir)){
            if($item!='.' 
             && $item!='..' 
             && $item!=basename(__FILE__)
    && $item != "index.php" 
    && $item != "core" 
            ){
                $items[]=$item;
            }   
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    natsort($items); //sort
    return $items;
}
?>
<!-- in HTML bobdy -->
...
<div class="msg"><?php echo $msg;?></div>
<div class="frames">
 <div id="dirs" class="frame">
  <div class="frame-title">Directories</div>
  <!-- generated dirs-list-links targeted to #files -->
  <iframe name="dirs" src="<?php echo $base_dir.'/index.php';?>"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div id="files" class="frame">
  <div class="frame-title">Files</div>
  <!-- generated files-list-links targeted to #file_preview -->
  <iframe name="files" src="<?php echo $data_dir.'/index.php';?>"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div id="file_preview" class="frame">
  <div class="frame-title">Preview</div>
  <iframe name="file_preview"><file.html></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

The directories and files are created correctly. But the "index" file is not copoied. Please, hint.

Comment: (a) Is the HTML relevant to the question? (b) Is the `getFiles()` function relevant to the question? (c) What does `copy()` return? (d) Why are you concatenating the paths in different ways, sometimes inserting a `/` between, sometimes not?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

read the index file you want to create into a variable

```
$current = file_get_contents($file);
```

then write the index file:

```
$targetIndexFile = '/newDirectory/index.html';
file_put_contents($targetIndexFile,$current;
```

That should allow you to effectively move a file from one directory to another.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But there is something new occurred:
adding `$file_description = $_POST['file_description'];
// write to file
if(isset($_POST['file_description']))
{
$data=$_POST['file_description'];
$fp = fopen($file_name.'.html', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}`
the new file is saved twice (in ./ and in the new dolfder) without a content, however.

Comment: This solved by: `$fp = fopen($base_dir.'/'.$data_dir.'/'.$file_name, 'a');`
The file_description is not written, however.

Comment: I don't know how, but everything works now.
THX a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a slash before `dir_index.php`:

```
copy($base_dir . '/' . 'dir_index.php',$base_dir.'/'.$data_dir.'.index.php');
```